# BackgroundImage layout to Bottom

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a task, that can be easily completed with html/css, but I cant figure out how to do it with C# `WindowsForms`.

I need to create container with dinamic height and with 3 types of `BackgroundImage`'s. To do so I created `panel1` and set `BackgroundImageLayout` of "body.jpg" to `tile`.
Then I put `panel2` and set `BackgroundImageLayout` of "top.jpg" to `none`.
So I need to create only one container with "bottom.jpg" but here is the problem.

Image is tall and it must have layout to bottom, but I cant set `BackgroundImage` of `panel3` to `Bottom` and I cant `dock` `PictureBox` to bottom, because in that case it will prevent to set content overlay.

P.S. Sorry if you cant understand some of my explanations - my native language is Russian.

Here is what constuctor created for me:

```
        // 
        // Charsheet_bg
        // 
        this.Charsheet_bg.AutoSize = true;
        this.Charsheet_bg.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("Charsheet_bg.BackgroundImage")));
        this.Charsheet_bg.Controls.Add(this.Charsheet_top);
        this.Charsheet_bg.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
        this.Charsheet_bg.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.Charsheet_bg.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.Charsheet_bg.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(285, 0);
        this.Charsheet_bg.Name = "Charsheet_bg";
        this.Charsheet_bg.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(285, 488);
        this.Charsheet_bg.TabIndex = 30;
        // 
        // Charsheet_top
        // 
        this.Charsheet_top.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.Charsheet_top.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("Charsheet_top.BackgroundImage")));
        this.Charsheet_top.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
        this.Charsheet_top.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Charsheet_top.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.Charsheet_top.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(285, 200);
        this.Charsheet_top.Name = "Charsheet_top";
        this.Charsheet_top.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(285, 488);
        this.Charsheet_top.TabIndex = 31;
```

And screenshot will be in 5 mins.

[Screenshot with tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwbOq.jpg)

Comment: Sometimes screenshot and piece of xaml/cs worth thousands of words.

Comment: Top http://i.stack.imgur.com/TvpEt.jpg
Body http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mjn5.jpg
Bottom http://i.stack.imgur.com/92uZg.jpg